# filter array in odd and even and then assign into key and value respective value

Tags: php

i have array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => +918800499626
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => asdasd
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 342423
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => assssssss
        )

)
```

and i want to array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => +918800499626
            [carrier] => asdasd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           [number] => 342423 
           [carrier] => assssssss
        )
)
```

something like this.
Help will be appriciated. thanks

Comment: "Help" implies that you're doing some of the work. What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried to get odd and even array with their index but after i am stuck to merge odd and even index in to array.

Comment: Show the code that you've tried and explain how it's not working.

Comment: '$odd = array();
$even = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if ($k % 2 == 0) {
        $even[] = $v;
    }
    else {
        $odd[] = $v;
    }
}'

Comment: Please edit your post to show the code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it not so much as even and odd as alternating entries. So we use a "normal" `for` loop with an `$i++` increment on it, but also add in a `++$i` within the code. This means that each time through the loop, `$i` actually gets incremented twice.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($inputArray); $i++)
{
    if(isset($inputArray[$i]) && isset($inputArray[$i+1]))
    {
        $resultArray[] = array("number"=>$inputArray[$i]["number"], "carrier"=>$inputArray[++$i]["carrier"]);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/mviBu)

Answer (score 0):

I think that easiest way to use loops. For that case I wrote code:

```
$arResult = array();
foreach ($arData as $key => $arValue) {
    $arResult[intval($key/2)][key($arValue)] = $arValue[key($arValue)];
}
```

$arData - your first array.
[Here is demo link.](http://3v4l.org/fePG0)